# Wordpress - meta_query does not work with values above 1 million

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this code:

```
$args3 = array(
                        'post_type'  => 'imoveis_a_venda',
                        'cat'        => $categoria,
                        'meta_query' => array(
                          array(
                            'key' => 'valor',
                            'value' => array($amount1,$amount2),
                            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                            'type' => 'NUMERICAL'
                            ),
                          )

                        );
```

to values ​​between 0 and 999.999,00 works perfectly. 
But when passes 1 million does not work.

Comment: Do you get an error when the value _does not work_? Also, does `NUMERICAL` really work as a type? It [looks like](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query) the only available `type`s are: 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR', 'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED'. Default value is 'CHAR'.`... Also, how you define the numeric data might matter; the values should probably only be numbers (and possibly decimal points...) _but, most likely, no commas_...

Comment: No error appears. Only thing that happens is that the reading of the data (between two values) does not work when the values ​​are 1 million upwards. If the amount is less than 1 million (between 0 and 999,999.99) operates normally. 

NOTE: the right type is 'NUMERIC' same. Put and still the problem.

Comment: How do your `$amount1` and `$amount2` variables look? _(i.e. What exact values are going into these two variables?)_

Comment: You can view here: http://rage123testando.com.br/cidade_campo/ the search filter in the left column. Values ​​when you click on "BUSCAR" are sent via $_GET for the url. And the url comes from the values ​​of  and $amount1 $amount2. 
You can set the value of amount1 and amount2 direct by URL.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to see the values of `$amount1` and `$amount2` on the website; would you be able to add an example of the _low_ and _high_ values in your question above?

Answer (score 0):

Set type in meta_query to SIGNED.

```
$args3 = array(
                  'post_type'  => 'imoveis_a_venda',
                  'cat'        => $categoria,
                  'meta_query' => array(
                      array(
                        'key' => 'valor',
                        'value' => array($amount1,$amount2),
                        'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        'type' => 'SIGNED'
                        ),
                    )

           );
```